# postgres - slow outer query when using a primary key

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

Using Postgres v. 8.4.2.

I have a standard three-table setup for a many-to-many relationship.  A query, written against two of these tables, is supposed to return a single record for which there is no existing mapping:

```
SELECT b.id
   FROM scm_branch b
      LEFT OUTER JOIN "scm_branchgroup_branches" bgb
         ON b.id = bgb.branch_id
   WHERE
         bgb.branch_id is NULL
   LIMIT 1
```

(scm_branchgroup_branches is the ternary table keeping the mapping records)

this query has the following top level cost:

> Limit  (cost=0.00..0.22 rows=1 width=4)

However if I change the field used in the WHERE condition to be the primary key of the bgb table, the cost goes drastically up:

```
SELECT b.id
   FROM scm_branch b
      LEFT OUTER JOIN "scm_branchgroup_branches" bgb
         ON b.id = bgb.branch_id
   WHERE
         bgb.id IS NULL 
   LIMIT 1
```

(note: this query uses "bgb.id IS NULL" vs "bgb.branch_id is NULL" used in the previous example)

Top level cost:

> Limit  (cost=236366.74..4644900.75 rows=1 width=4)

**Why such a drastic difference?**  I mean I see the difference in execution plans, but I don't understand the underlying reasons for the difference.

I'll be happy to provide any additional info needed to answer this question.

Thanks
D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the version with `branch_id IS NULL`, PostgreSQL recognizes that you're doing an anti-join, and it optimizes accordingly, using a "hash-join"-type algorithm. (Google [`PostgreSQL hash left anti-join`](https://www.google.com/search?q=PostgreSQL%20hash%20left%20anti-join) for lots of information on this optimization.) In the version with `id IS NULL`, however, it doesn't recognize this fact, and its optimizations are not nearly so helpful. What's more, the join basically forces it to use the index on `branch_id`, so it can't take advantage of the primary-key index on `id`, and must consult the actual table data to determine if a given record satisfies the WHERE-clause.

(There may well be other factors at play as well — I'm not an expert on PostgreSQL — but I believe those are the main factors.)

Comment: Ah, makes sense.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  The slow query is issued by Django ORM. I don't think there is built-in anti-join support in it, but at least now I can ask the right questions.